# Docker container crashing ubuntu host

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

Very unexpected, but briefly if i run a docker container host becomes unresponsive, no in/out, can't ping it, only hard reboot works.

DMESG, sys and kernel logs doesn't show anything obvious

Heuristic diagnosis tells me it crashes when my client terminal kicking docker hibernates...

It's very fuzzy, but maybe someone experienced something similar?

host spec:

```
Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU  Z3735F @ 1.33GHz
```

ubuntu version

```
~$ uname -a
Linux raccoon 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

docker -v

```
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
```

Comment: I'm seeing these same symptoms on Ubuntu 17.04 and Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

Comment: I'm also seeing more or less the same symptoms on Debian Wheezy (3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.51-3 (2017-12-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux) with Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6. Differences: the host does not freeze immediatly, but within 1 hour up to several days. But in the end, it always freezez! The data is written to a MySQL-Server, that is running on the host itself...

Comment: Small correction: Debian Jessie, not Wheezy

Comment: And: this is not a hardware issue! I witnessed the crash on a root server and talked the support into replacing the whole hardware (expect the disks), but afterwards, the same crashes still happen.

Comment: It is almost 2021 now and I still have a similar issue. Ubuntu and Windows work well until I run docker images on Ubuntu 20.04, once in a while entires system freezes, no response, only hard reset. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can testify I still get the same crashes in 2021

Comment: Test your RAM for hardware errors.